# No puedo acceder en mi login despues de cerrar sesion

Tags: html, laravel

Tengo un ecommerce el cual tiene un login para ciertos usuarios. El login funciona y te da acceso, el problema esta cuando cierras sesión, al cerrar sesion redirecciono al login y cuando quieres acceder de nuevo no te deja acceder, tengo que volver cargar la url para que funcione, lo cual se me hace muy raro, pienso que es la manera en que cierro la sesión. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Código para cerrar sesión:

```
$linkLogin = DB::table('empresas')->select('path_login')->where('empresa_id',session('empresa_id'))->first();
    Auth::guard('customer')->logout();
    session()->flush();
    $request->session()->forget('customers_id');
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return Redirect::to($linkLogin->path_login);
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *no te deja acceder*?, ¿marca algún error?, ¿te dice que no existe el recurso?, ¿puedes explicar mejor el comportamiento actual?

Comment: Será por que usas regenerate luego de forget ?? Si estás saliendo de sesión, por la generas nuevamente ??? O me equivoco ?? -> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session

Comment: No me manda ningun error. Tengo validaciones para el formulario pero no me manda ningun error.

Comment: ¿No vasta con esto: `Auth::guard('customer')->logout(); return Redirect::to($linkLogin->path_login);` ?

Comment: No, ya lo intente y sigue igual